# Uploading Data into Redis

Tags: json, database, redis

I am working on school project where we need to create website and use Redis to search database, in my case it will be movie database. I got JSON file with names and ratings of 100 movies. I would like to upload this dataset into Redis instead on entering the entire dataset manually. JSON file is saved on my desktop and I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Is there a way to do it?

I have never used Redis so my question might be very silly. I've been looking all over the internet and cannot find exactly what needs to be done. I might be googling incorrect question maybe that's why I cannot find the answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the RedisJSON module for Redis? https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisJSON

Answer (score 0):

Write an appropriate program to do the job. There's no one-size-fits-all process because how your data is structured in redis is up to you; once you decide on that, it should be easy to write a program to parse the JSON and insert the data.